# JPA NamedQueries with PK Entities

Tags: orm, jpa

I have generated Entity Classes using Netbeans.
My Class has a composite primary key so Netbeans generated an additional PK Entity Class for me.
I wish to use a NamedQuery in the Entity class but as the param I am passing into the named query is Embedded in the PK class, the NamedQuery call is failing and the query does not seem to be complete.

Can anyone offer an example of what my code should look like to use a NamedQuery which has a composite PK (@EmbeddedId association) in it? The following fails:

Facade Class (part):

```
@Stateless
public class EMyEntityFacade extends AbstractFacade<EMyEntity> {

public EMyEntityFacade() {
    super(EMyEntity.class);
}

//does not work
/*
private Query queryByComp1Id(int comp1Id) {
    Query query = this.getEntityManager().createNamedQuery("EMyEntity.findByComp1Id");
    query.setParameter("comp1Id", comp1Id);
    return query;
}
*/

//any nearer?
private Query queryByComp1d(int comp1Id) {
    EMyEntityPK eMyEntityPK = new EMyEntityPK();

    Query query = this.getEntityManager().createNamedQuery("EMyEntity.findByComp1Id");

    eMyEntityPK.setComp1Id(comp1Id);

    //how do I pass the eMyEntityPK through to the Entity so the query is well formed? 
    //???

    return query;
}

public List<EMyEntity> findByComp1Id(int comp1Id) {
    Query query = queryByComp1Id(comp1Id);
    return query.getResultList();
}
```

Entity Class (part):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "my_entity")
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "EMyEntity.findByComp1Id",
    query = "SELECT e FROM EMyEntity e WHERE e.eMyEntityPK.comp1Id = :comp1Id"),...)})

public class EMyEntity implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @EmbeddedId
    protected EMyEntityPK eMyEntityPK;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "inherit_from_parent")
    ...
    ...
}
```

PK Class (part):

```
@Embeddable
public class EMyEntityPK implements Serializable {
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "comp1_id")
    private int comp1Id;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "comp2_id")
    private int comp2Id;
    ...
    ...
}
```

Comment: show the exception and the stacktrace

Comment: I don't see any error. The named query is ok. Where are you having problem?

Answer (score 1):

You should pass the who object representing the primary key, not just one field of it. If you need to query for part of the pk, symply refer to it in the where clause :`where pk.fld=`

Comment: Thanks Bozho, can you possibly post some example code please? The NamedQuery already has the 'WHERE e.eMyEntityPK.comp1Id =: comp1Id' in its where clause. Thank you.

Comment: Show me your query and you entity, and pk object